# Симметрическое удаление дерева

Tags: c, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Нужно удалить узлы дерева в **симметрическом порядке справа налево**. Написала код для прямого удаления, а вот как реализовать симметрическое?

```
void FreeTree(TreeNode* proot) // указатель на корень дерева
{
    if (proot == NULL) // дерево пустое
        return;
    FreeTree(proot->right); // удаление правого поддерева
    FreeTree(proot->left); // удаление левого поддерева
    free(proot); // удаление корня
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если симметричный — это левый потомок, корень, правый потомок, то

```
void FreeTree(TreeNode* proot) // указатель на корень дерева
{
    if (proot == NULL) // дерево пустое
        return;
    FreeTree(proot->left); // удаление левого поддерева
    TreeNode* right = proot->right;
    free(proot); // удаление корня
    FreeTree(right); // удаление правого поддерева
}
```

Вы это хотели?